# Is Lord Narayana omniscient and omnipotent?

Tags: vishnu

Is Lord Narayana omniscient and omnipotent? Can you suggest quotes from the scriptures to support this?

Comment: [Narayana Sukta](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/narayana-sukta.html?lang=sa) appearing in Yajurveda and [Anu-narayana Upanishad](http://www.sathyasaiottawa.org/pdf/Vedam/Narayana_Upanishad.pdf) declare Lord Narayana to be Omniscient and Omnipresent.

Comment: @ManojGowda That looks like an answer to me if it has some more elaboration and explanation. Please post it as an answer instead of comment.

Comment: this is a duplicate of your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the various attributes or qualities of Lord Narayana as per the scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/what-are-the-various-attributes-or-qualities-of-lord-narayana-as-per-the-scriptu)

Comment: Yes and so is Shiva.

Answer (score 9):

## Is lord narayana omniscient and omnipotent ?

**Yes , Lord Narayana is omniscient and omnipotent** . In Hinduism   Lord Narayana is worshiped as  supreme Lord in Vaishnavism and is also known as Lord Vishnu.  He is the Supreme Purusha of Purusha Sukta of vedas.

[**The Lakshmi Tantra**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pENlKmZ4r94C&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=Lord%20narayana%20is%20omniscient%20and%20omnipotent&source=bl&ots=TjqeAPSsjd&sig=sKEpd9ZyAaK7SWJ5e4YB9ot_oxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji-NXNvoLcAhWLuI8KHV-LAuI4ChDoAQhNMAY#v=onepage&q=Lord%20narayana%20is%20omniscient%20and%20omnipotent&f=false) is one of the Pāñcarātra texts, which are dedicated to the worship of Narayana (Vishnu) and form part of the Agamas. The text in its chapter 50 - The Power of Shree-Sukta describes Lord Narayana as omniscient and omnipotent.

> श्री  देवो नारायणो नाम जगतस्तस्थुषस्पति : |
>  आत्मा च सर्वलोकानां
> षाडगुण्यानन्दविग्रह ||
>  सर्वप्रकृतिरिशान : सर्वज्ञ सर्वकार्यकृत
> |
>  निरनिष्ठोsनवद्यच्श्र  सर्वकल्याणसंश्रय ||6 ||
>
> 5-10. Sri -:  God Narayana   is lord over (all things) movable and
> immovable. Embodying the six attributes and bliss. He is the self
> (essence) of all worlds , the material cause of all (created things) ,
> the sovereign ruler , **omniscient , omnipotent** , free from all
> misfortune , flawless and the repository of all that is beneficial .
> Being self-luminous  , he illuminates both darkness and light ; He is
> the inner lord (self abiding in every being) , the controller manifest
> in (both) the positive and negative (phenomena).

---

Here is the  Lakshmi Tantra shlokas in
[**sanskrit**](https://archive.org/stream/LakshmiTantra/Lakshmi%20Tantra%201975%20VKrishnamacharya#page/n263/mode/2up)
and [**more**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshmi_Tantra) about the text.

Answer (score 7):

The first line in Narayana Sukta says this:

> सहस्र शीर्षं देवं विश्वाक्षं विश्वशंभुवम् ।
>
> विश्वै नारायणं देवं अक्षरं परमं पदम् ॥

Sahasrasheersham means He has innumerable heads (although sahasra means thousand, in this case it should be understood as innumerable). The One with innumerable heads is present everywhere and is witness to all that happens in this Universe. So, this is a proof of omniscient nature of Narayana.

In Vishnu Sahasranama, Vishnu (also known as Narayana) is addressed as **Aniruddha**, meaning the **Unhindered one**.

> maheṣvāsō mahībhartā śrīnivāsaḥ satāṁ gatiḥ |
>
> aniruddhaḥ surānandō gōvindō gōvidāṁ patiḥ ||

Unhindered here means He is capable of doing anything (in the interest of Dharma). So, Lord Narayana (Vishnu) is both omniscient and omnipotent.

Further, in Anu-narayana Upanishad, the following verses indicate Narayana's omnipotence. I am quoting the translation of the verses taken from [here](http://www.sathyasaiottawa.org/pdf/Vedam/Narayana_Upanishad.pdf).

> The supreme person Narayana willed to create beings
>
> From Narayana emerged the life principle
>
> From Narayana emerged the mind and all the senses
>
> From Narayana came the wind, the light, the water and the Earth, which became the constituents of the Universe
>
> From Narayana came the Creator Brahma
>
> From Narayana emerged Maha-Rudra, the annihilator
>
> From Narayana came Indra, all the Prajapathis,  the twelve sons (of Aditi), the eight vasus, the Rudra and all the Vedas
>
> All beings emerged from Narayana
>
> Narayana sustains all beings
>
> Every being merges in Narayana

The very essence of Anu-narayana Upanishad is that Lord Narayana is Omnipotent. He as Brahma creates the Universe, He Himself sustains it and He as Rudra destroys in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Brahmá to Náráyańa:

> vyaktāvyaktasvarūpastvaṃ samaṣṭivyaṣṭirūpavān /
>
> **sarvajña**ḥsarvanit**sarvaśakti**jñānabalardhimān // [ViP_5,1.47](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/visnup_u.htm) //
>
> ---
>
> Thou art both discrete and indiscrete, universal and individual, **omniscient**, all-seeing, **omnipotent**, possessed of all wisdom and strength and power.
>
> [VISHŃU PURÁŃA.BOOK V.CHAP. I.](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp118.htm)

Comment: @sv. You edited the answer here also Good good