# What are the various attributes or qualities of Lord Narayana as per the scriptures?

Tags: vishnu

What are the various attributes or qualities of Lord Narayana as per the scriptures, for eg. omniscience, omnipotence, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

Lord Vishnu has infinite attributes. He is called "*Aprameya*" meaning who is undefinable. He is beyond the reach of shastras, our senses to define hm completely. Hence, we cannot get a complete idea on what are his attributes completely. We can define him and his attributes based on what is said in the texts, our experiences but that would be equal to a drop in the ocean.

However, Vishnu Sahasranama stotram present in the Anushasana Parva, Mahabharata gives thousand names of Lord Vishnu which are indicative of his attributes.

> yāni nāmāni gauṇāni vikhyātāni mahātmanaḥ|
>   ṛṣibhiḥ parigītāni tāni vakṣyāmi bhūtayē ||
>
> I am giving for the benefit of all, those names of His which are far-famed, which are indicative of His attributes, and which find a place in the exalted hymns of the ṛṣis.

You can have a look at the names and attributes given in the Vishnu Sahasranamam with a commentary of Adi Shankaracharya on [shivkumar.org](http://www.shivkumar.org/music/vishnu-sahasranamam-meanings.htm).

Parthasarathy, K.E. adds Adi Shankaracharya and Sri Parashara Bhattar's commentaries in his book *Sri Visnu Sahasranamam*.

There are many names and attributes which are not listed in the Vishnu Sahasranama because the ones named in the stotram are popular ones. So, the number of attributes are limitless.

Comment: yes, It's impossible to know Vishnu completely. Even one line of Vishnu Stuti says the same... _"Lakshmi Kantama Kamal Nayanama **Yoghridyanigamyama**"_ Here the meaning of highlighted text is, _"It's impossible to know him completely Even for the greatest Saints/Maharishis of all time"_.

Comment: @Rishabh It's impossible to know but the meaning of the text you quoted is "One who is consort of Lakshmi, lotus eyed, the one who is the destination Yogis try to reach through their dhyanam (meditation) ".

Comment: I searched on google long ago about meaning of complete Vishnu Stuti coz I use to sing it on fast. [Here is the link](https://vnktchari.blogspot.com/2015/09/vishnu-stuti-lyrics-and-meaning-prayers.html#.WzsMnyDhW1s) in which I found the meaning. I don't know how much this site is correct about the meaning but this site says the same which I quoted. Let me know if this site is wrong coz I don't want to keep wrong info regarding Vishnu Stuti (And I told meaning of only highlighted text) :)

Comment: AS already mentioned by few as above, we have to believe that every body had their grand-grand father,though we have not seen them in person,but we believe the information passed on to us by our father/mother or known relative/thru friend circle.
similarly,when we refer to SRIMADBHAGAVATHA-3-15-36/37/38.Sanakaadi munis claims they met lord Srimannarayana & exchanged their views.

Comment: They also narrates the design of the abode of lord Srimannarayana.Should we not consider that,there is a well established link with King PARIKSHIT at the end of DWAPARA YUGAM,who also mentions that he could speak to sanakadi munis,King parikshit is the grand son of ARJUNA (PANDAVAs)in Mahabharatha. ONE EXAMPLE : we ourselves can question; can we see our own internal wish [MANAS], we all sure, that we can experience. Similarly, to an electric current in a conductor.which you cannot see but you get a shock when you touch it.

Answer (score 1):

True, Vishnu is limitless as confirmed by these verses in Srimad Bhagavatam. 
In [Bhagavatam 1.18.3](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/18/23), we find

> O ṛṣis, who are as powerfully pure as the sun, I shall try to describe to you the transcendental pastimes of Viṣṇu as far as my knowledge is concerned. As the birds fly in the sky as far as their capacity allows, so do the learned devotees describe the Lord as far as their realization allows.

In [Bhagavatam 11.26.30](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/26/30), Krishna says

> What more remains to be accomplished for the perfect devotee after achieving devotional service unto Me, the Supreme Absolute Truth, whose qualities are innumerable and who am the embodiment of all ecstatic experience?